# remotely changing rust(game) role with Wordpress Homepage

Tags: wordpress

I have a Rust gameserver and a shop for the rust gameserver on a wordpress website.

My Question is: How can i give a player a role like vip on the gameserver after he has purchases for example a vip kit in the shop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your shop? Woocommerce? Something else? What have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: I use Woocommerce and i searched in the Internet for many hours but i found nothing.

Comment: You may have searched for hours, but this question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. You are essentially asking for a custom solution to something.